# How does HP's BIOS Graphics "Auto" decide which one to choose?

Tags: bios, centos, nvidia-graphics-card, redhat-enterprise-linux, integrated-graphics

The HP Z15-G3 has a Graphics drop-down menu in the BIOS with the available options:

- Auto
- Discrete Graphics
- Hybrid Graphics

Exactly how does "Auto" work?

In the HP Z15-G2 BIOS Manual it says, "When set to Auto, Hybrid Graphics is disabled for certain Linux OS.", is that the same for the G3? Which Linux OSs?

Comment: I'd check the system and X logs resulting from each option.

Comment: I have been, and the only consistent way I can get "Auto" to switch is by having an External CD/DVD Drive connected at bootup, which makes no sense whatsoever